# JavaScript - Is there a more efficient way to create option elements?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, loops, dom

I'm trying to create an html select list with 10,000 options. Because of the number, I need it to be as efficient as possible. I've gotten it working, but I think it's pretty inefficient

```
var select = document.createElement("select");
document.body.appendChild(select);

for (var i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    var optionText = option.createTextNode("option" + i);
    option.value = "option" + i;
    option.appendChild(optionText);
    select.appendChild(option);
}
```

I've read that querying the DOM too much can be expensive. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: The expensive thing is repeatedly reading from DOM followed by changing DOM. Just changing DOM by itself is not that expensive. However, from UX side, your users will *hate* you if you give them a 10000-item select. With a *passion*. In your shoes I would try *very* hard to come up with an alternative UI solution.

Comment: Note it would be better to append the `select` at the end, once it has all the `option`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at this question from another angle. As a user I can probably tolerate even two second of generating this list (most probably it will take less than 2 seconds even on a bad phone), but **forcing me to select an element from a dropdown list of 10k elements - this is an overkill**.

I would completely ditch an "creating an option" and will investigate a better (from UI point of view) approach. Something like a [select autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) (this is just an example).

**P.S.** If you really really want your users to suffer by scrolling 10k elements, I would suggest take this part `select.appendChild(option);` out of the loop. Generate all you want to append and append them at once.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Is there a UX limit on the number of options you can show? Would 1000 still be too many? 100? What if you need to store a list of cities in the drop down

Comment: There is no hard limit, which mean that you can't say that 145 is too many, but 140 is ok. This is mostly how much a particular human can tolerate. I would say (but I am not a UI expert) that if the scroll list is bigger than 3/4 of a screen - this is too much. If you need a list of cities, I would in the beginning ask a person to select a country (it would be stupid to select an Egypt Memphis if you want to go to US Memphis). Then I would allow people to type the beginning and to autocomplete other things for them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Option` constructor](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-option):

> A constructor is provided for creating [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#htmloptionelement)
>   objects (in addition to the factory methods from DOM such as
>   `createElement()`):
>
> ```
> Option(text, value, defaultSelected, selected)
> ```
>
> When invoked as a constructor, it must return a new
>   [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#htmloptionelement) object (a new [`option`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element) element).
>
> If the first argument is not the empty string, the new object must
>   have as its only child a [`Text`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#text-0) node whose data is the value of
>   that argument. Otherwise, it must have no children.
>
> If the `value` argument is present, the new object
>   must have a [`value`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-value) attribute set with the value of the argument
>   as its value.
>
> If the `defaultSelected` argument is true, the new
>   object must have a [`selected`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-selected) attribute set with no value.
>
> If the `selected` argument is true, the new object
>   must have its [selectedness](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-option-selectedness) set to true; otherwise the
>   [selectedness](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-option-selectedness) must be set to false, even if the
>   `defaultSelected` argument is true.

In your case,

```
select.appendChild(new Option("option" + i));
```

Answer (score -2):

Please use innerHTML,if you want high performance

I give you a jsperf below:

http://jsperf.com/js-appendchild/3